# how to write a for(){} loop in R with multiple functions and multiple variables by condition?

Tags: r

#### I have a data set that looks like this.... and there are more variables...

but I am only interested in using the for(){} command to run some statistics on four of them.....  the dataset=b1

```
ELEV   SLOPE    ASPECT     presab
2342.569   0.297   109.502   1 
2280.851   0.997   106.433   2
2281.271   0.665    93.872   1
2277.854   2.407   215.193   2
2271.858   1.132    32.050   1
2229.149   0.000   270.000   1
```

#### using  for(){} how do I loop multiple statistical functions (mean,sd,length) to;

multiple variables (elev,slope,aspect); 
by presab; 
and export these as three R objects in the working environment???

#### This is as far as I have gotten..... can anyone help?

First I tried this..... and it kinda worked......

```
>i=1
>for (i in 1:1) {
    v1=tapply(b1$ASPECT,b1$presab,mean)
    v2=tapply(b1$ELEV,b1$presab,mean)
    v3=tapply(b1$SLOPE,b1$presab,mean)
    v4=cbind(v1,v2,v3)
    print(v4)}

#        v1       v2       v3
#1 137.3997 2400.974 4.075000
#2 131.2396 2400.301 3.306509
```

### I also tried this format....

```
>vars=c("b1$ELEV","b1$SLOPE","b1$ASPECT")
>i=1
>for (i in 1:3) {
    tapply(b1$ASPECT,b1$presab,mean),
    tapply(b1$ELEV,b1$presab,mean),
    tapply(b1$SLOPE,b1$presab,mean)}
```

#### any bread crumbs will help find my way home.....

Answer (score 1):

## Thank you all for your posting!

## I found a way to use looping using the for(){} function to build a matrix that worked quit well

```
>ex17out <- matrix(0,3,6)
for (i in 1:2) {
  temp <- subset(b3,presab==i)
  ex17out[1,i*3-2] <- mean(temp$ASPECT)
  ex17out[1,i*3-1] <- sd(temp$ASPECT)
  ex17out[1,i*3] <- length(temp$ASPECT)
  ex17out[1,i*3-2] <- mean(temp$ASPECT)
  ex17out[1,i*3-1] <- sd(temp$ASPECT)
  ex17out[1,i*3] <- length(temp$ASPECT)
  ex17out[2,i*3-2] <- mean(temp$ELEV)
  ex17out[2,i*3-1] <- sd(temp$ELEV)
  ex17out[2,i*3] <- length(temp$ELEV)
  ex17out[2,i*3-2] <- mean(temp$ELEV)
  ex17out[2,i*3-1] <- sd(temp$ELEV)
  ex17out[2,i*3] <- length(temp$ELEV)
  ex17out[3,i*3-2] <- mean(temp$SLOPE)
  ex17out[3,i*3-1] <- sd(temp$SLOPE)
  ex17out[3,i*3] <- length(temp$SLOPE)
  ex17out[3,i*3-2] <- mean(temp$SLOPE)
  ex17out[3,i*3-1] <- sd(temp$SLOPE)
  ex17out[3,i*3] <- length(temp$SLOPE)
  }
>ex17out
 

           [,1]      [,2] [,3]       [,4]       [,5] [,6]
[1,]  131.599609 86.628193   46  135.00713  75.039541  182
[2,] 2276.916891 44.433890   46 2431.90777 179.167677  182
[3,]    4.066087  4.654311   46    3.59589   4.826945  182
```

Answer (score 0):

A way using a custom function and the `plyr` package.

First, you build a function that computes summary statistics of your choice and return as a named vector:

```
statistics <- function(x, na.omit=TRUE){
  fun_names <- c("Length", "Mean", "SD")

  if(na.omit)
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]

  n <- length(x)
  m <- mean(x)
  s <- sd(x)

  stats <- c(n,m,s)
  names(stats) <- fun_names
  return(stats)
}
```

Then, you apply this function to all variables you want, within each peace data.frame defined by `presab`. `ddply` from `plyr` package make this task a peace of cake:

```
library(plyr)

summary <- ddply(b1, "presab", function(df) statistics(df[ , sapply(df, is.numeric)]))
```

a small explanation of what is going on here: ddply will split up the data.frame `b1` by `presab` values and will apply the (anonymous) function in each one of them. This function will compute the statistics of all the numeric variables that exists in `b1`. The `sapply(df, is.numeric)` part ensures that only numeric variables will be attempted to have their summaries computed.

hope it helps!